# How to get data during the time span without looping

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    $dateArr = array("2011-10-15","2011-10-16","2011-10-17")

    foreach $dateArr as $value)
    {
        $query = SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `captureTime` >= $value.' 00:00:01' AND `captureTime` <= $value.' 23:59:59' GROUP BY FLOOR(HOUR(captureTime) / 4)
    }
```

As seen from the above query, the captureTime on the same date with different time

```
eg, captureTime >= '2011-10-15 00:00:00' AND captureTime <='2011-10-15 23:59:59'
    captureTime >= '2011-10-16 00:00:00' AND captureTime <='2011-10-16 23:59:59'
    captureTime >= '2011-10-17 00:00:00' AND captureTime <='2011-10-17 23:59:59'
```

All data can be retrived from database using the above code. However, the number of the $dateArr element will be growth...maybe more than 100, so it will loop for >100 times in the above approach.

Then I changed query to the following:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `captureTime` >= '2011-10-15 00:00:01' AND `captureTime` <= '2011-10-17 23:59:59' GROUP BY FLOOR(HOUR(captureTime) / 4)
```

Seen from this query:

```
captureTime >= '2011-10-15 00:00:00' AND captureTime <='2011-10-17 23:59:59'
```

However, only data on 2011-10-15 can be got from database and there is no data on the rest of two days.

So my question is How to get all data from DB without loop?

BTW: `GROUP BY FLOOR(HOUR(captureTime) / 4)` have to be used in the query in this case.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the loop is for, but if you use BETWEEN (as I specified bellow) then GROUP BY DAY(captureTime) should give you results for each day separately

Comment: You are using SELECT * with GROUP BY and there is no aggregation used? How could that work? What exactly is your output and how do you determine that only 2011-10-15 data is output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the BETWEEN opertor, which uses also AND, but in that case it is not a logical AND. Example:

captureTime BETWEEN '2011-10-15 00:00:00' AND '2011-10-17 23:59:59'

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype for captureTime? 
If it is datetime then better use BETWEEN instead of comparison operators.

e.g.

$query = SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `captureTime` BETWEEN '2011-10-15 00:00:01' AND '2011-10-17 23:59:59' GROUP BY FLOOR(HOUR(captureTime) / 4)

PS. Above query not fired so can have syntax errors